# Laggy behavior on inspector for Facebook Unity SDK 4.3.6

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

After import the latest version facebook unity sdk(4.3.6) into unity and I tried to edit setting in inspector,I just find it is impossible to fill in the "App ID" field or re-size the inspector panel because of its high latency.No problems found if not using menu from imported plug-in in the inspector.

The inspector did not show any detailed information about the openssl installed such as version, path to detect,etc.
Set path at System Properties>Advanced>Environment variables>System Variables but the plug-in cannot detect it anyway.

I am confused with the compatiblity of  facebook unity sdk since Facebook SDK for Unity 4.3.4 on unity asset store just mentioned the required version of unity is 4.3+ which is different from the official page of facebook(The Facebook Unity SDK works with Unity 4.2 and above).

Any experienced user of facebook unity sdk 4.3.6 can give some comments?

-using Unity3d 4.2.0

-installed openssl v1.0.1e

Comment: THe Unity asset store automatically assigns the version of Unity that you used to build the plugin as the minimum required version.  We only require version 4.2 of Unity.  As for the lagginess, can you tell me what OS are running?

Comment: When i just upgrade the unity to 4.3+ and set the path in system preference, lagginess is elimiated.
OS: win 7 (32/64) on two laptops.

Answer (score 0):

Just has the same problem.

When i added my 'keytool' java to the right path is all started to work ok again.

I guess that it had got to do with searching for the 'keytool' application.